# Reading value from Firebase Android and update it

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I want to get `productQuantity` value and update it:

```
private void updateValue() {

        try {
            newQuantity = Integer.parseInt(editTextQuantity.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            editTextQuantity.setError("Enter Charger Quantity");
            return;
        }

        DatabaseReference mReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mReference.child("goods").child("charger").orderByChild("productQuantity").equalTo(quantity)
                .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(newQuantity);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });


    }
```

I used `addChildEventListener` but it did not work on quantity the old value and newQuantity the new value.

Comment: Try: equalTo(quantity + "") to convert quantity to string since you keep quantity as a string in the database.

Comment: quantity stored in database as int

Comment: In the screenshot you shared the quantity is stored as a string, as shown by the quotes around the value.

Comment: It's an old screenshot before I make some changes to the code anyway I've replaced it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take an example. Let's say we want to get the product which has the `productQuantity` property set to `362` and we want to increase it by 10. To achieve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("goods").child("charger").orderByChild("productQuantity").equalTo(362);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            int productQuantity = ds.child("productQuantity").getValue(Integer.class);
            int newQuantity = productQuantity + 10;
            ds.child("productQuantity").getRef().setValue(newQuantity);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```